# How to configure Parse Server with new FCM (Android) credentials instead of "server key"

Tags: parse-platform, firebase-cloud-messaging

Firebase [will remove support for legacy APIs in June 2024](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1).

The Firebase UI no longer provides a "server key", but requires [other means of authenticating](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1#update-authorization-of-send-requests).

However, the Parse Server docs still [say to provide a "server key"](https://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/#fcm-android):

> To get your FCM API key, go to the Firebase console and navigate to the project. Navigate to the settings of the project, and within the “Cloud Messaging” tab, you will find it, labeled “Server key”

So I wonder, is there a way to use the new means of authentication with Parse Server? How, specifically?

Or is Parse Server simply incompatible with this change and will not be usable with Firebase after June 2024?